# Stripe in a Cordova app redirects the browser instead of loading the checkout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, stripe-payments

I'm trying to bootstrap the default simple javascript integration of Stripe inside a cordova app using the steps defined in https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple.

The script loads correctly and the button is created accordingly. The issue is that when i click on pay with card, instead of loading the checkout in a lightbox over my app, the cordova browser is redirected to https://checkout.stripe.com/v3/mobile.

I've acomplished to get the custom form payment on the app using angularjs, but i would like to get the original stripe layer over my app.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior for Stripe Checkout in a Cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
StripeCheckout.__app.setForceView('IframeView');
StripeCheckout.__app.setForceManhattan(true);
```

before calling  StripeCheckout.configure

beware though this is undocumented, and stripe are liable to change the code behind it!